# MS Access, Javascript SQL "Where"- Query

Tags: ms-access, client-side, jscript

I'm stuck with a simple query using JS to fetch data from MS Access database.
Connection and everything else working fine.

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE [tbl_1].dshb_name = '"+showDashboard+"' AND [tbl_2].monkpi_name ='"+showKPI+"'AND [tbl_3].mnth="+DateValueHere+"";

Everything works fine when I delete the second AND part , which contain the date .

I get "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.."

Comment: Are you positive that query works fine when you delete the second AND part?  Seems to me the Access engine would be confused by `[tbl_1]` and `[tbl_2]` since `tblname` is the only data source referenced in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Also you must format your date value as a proper string expression like, say: `mnth = #" + "2015/11/20" + "#"`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a *parameterized query*, like this:

```js
var adDate = 7;
var adVarWChar = 202;
var adParamInput = 1;

// test data
var showDashboard = "test_dshb";
var showKPI = "test_kpi";
var dateValueHere = new Date(2015, 10, 20);  // November 20, 2015

var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
conn.Open( 
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;"
        );
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = 
        "SELECT * FROM tblname " +
        "WHERE dshb_name=? AND monkpi_name=? AND mnth=?";
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDate, adParamInput));

cmd.Parameters(0).Value = showDashboard;
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = showKPI;
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = dateValueHere.getVarDate();
var rst = cmd.Execute();
while (!rst.EOF) {
    WScript.Echo(rst(0).Value);
    rst.MoveNext();
}

rst.Close();
conn.Close();
```

If you want to retrieve the results for an entire month then one way you could do it would be

```js
var adDate = 7;
var adVarWChar = 202;
var adParamInput = 1;

// test data
var showDashboard = "test_dshb";
var showKPI = "test_kpi";
var dateValueHere = new Date(2015, 0, 1);  // January 1, 2015

var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
conn.Open( 
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;"
        );
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = 
        "SELECT * FROM tblname " +
        "WHERE dshb_name=? AND monkpi_name=? " +
            "AND mnth>=? AND mnth<DateAdd('m', 1, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDate, adParamInput));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDate, adParamInput));

cmd.Parameters(0).Value = showDashboard;
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = showKPI;
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = dateValueHere.getVarDate();
cmd.Parameters(3).Value = dateValueHere.getVarDate();
var rst = cmd.Execute();
while (!rst.EOF) {
    WScript.Echo(rst(0).Value);
    rst.MoveNext();
}

rst.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: @ Gord Thompson: Thanks very much , mate. You helped me a lot. It was about proper formatting of my date value. Now everything is working fine. But I would like to use "DateAdd function" instead of using this:  ...AND tbl_MonitorValues.mnth >=#" + startMnth + "# AND tbl_MonitorValues.mnth <=#" + endMnth + "#" . Any hints ?  Thank you

Comment: One of the advantages of using a parameterized query is that you don't have to worry about date formatting. Notice that the code above does not use `#` delimiters and passes a real date value (using the `.getVarDate()` method) as the parameter value. If you are still fussing with date *formats* then you are either not using a parameterized query or you're using it wrong. As for using `DateAdd()`, it is not clear what you actually want to accomplish. You probably should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33831542/edit) your question to show your current code and what you *really* want to do.